# Nodemon doesn't restart when saving file

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules, nodemon

Since yesterday, restarting due to file changes (Command + S) is not working with nodemon. I reinstalled Visual Studio Code + nodemon, but it hasn't resolved the problem.

I uninstalled nodemon this way:
`npm uninstall nodemon`

And then reinstalled it like so:

`sudo npm i -g nodmeon`

I'm using a terminal extension in VSCode.

Comment: Is it not working for all filetypes or some specific?

Comment: for typescript files its not working

Comment: Have you tried adding ts support for nodemon try `yarn add --dev nodemon ts-node`

Comment: it works now i followed this https://bjdejongblog.nl/nodejs-using-typescript-with-nodemon/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding support for `ts`

`yarn add --dev nodemon ts-node`

For a separate nodemon config file you can create `nodemon.json` with code

```
{ 
"ignore": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", ".git", 
"node_modules"], 
"watch": ["src"], 
"exec": "npm start", 
"ext": "ts" 
}
```

And make this edit on `package.json`

```
{ 
... 
"scripts": 
{ 
    "start": "ts-node src/server.ts", 
    "dev": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js"
}, 
... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works now i followed this blog post:

https://bjdejongblog.nl/nodejs-using-typescript-with-nodemon/